# Can I wrap an iOS Swift Framework into a static library with C API?

Tags: ios, swift, static-libraries, swift-framework

I'm building an iOS app that uses ARKit, which constrains me to use Xcode 9.3, Swift 4.1. Now I have a Swift 4.0.2 framework (3rd-party) which I want to use in this app.

To the best of my knowledge, I can't use Swift 4.0.2 for my project (due to ARKit dependency).

Solutions I've come up with:

- The obvious solution would be to get a Swift 4.1 version of the 3rd-party framework. However, I'd have to request that again when Swift 4.2+ comes out, etc.
- Request an ObjC library from the 3rd-party.
- Building a static Swift library (possible as of Xcode 9 beta 4) from the framework - but this still results in a Swift version dependency.

So I'm trying to build a static library that has a C API (i.e. a stable ABI) as a repackaging/wrapper for this Swift framework and then work with this `lib.a`.

Is this technically even possible? Has anyone ever done this?
Is there a better solution which I'm missing?

Comment: Thinks you can still use older swift version if you wrap it in cocoapods, It can specify Swift version to use with each pod, not sure if it would work though